# Remove blur from message container

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I applied blur for body but i want to remove it for message container. How can i do it ? please i need your help i lost too much time on finding a solution. 
On close button the message disappears and the blur is removed for body.
My only problem is that blur property is applied for message container.
Before if success all the body is normal. All the change is after if success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>

#card  {
position: absolute;
top:30px;
width: 340px;
margin:-5px 0 0 -400px;

display: block;

text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;

 }

#upper-side {
padding: 2em;
background-color:  #3CB371;
display: block;
color: #fff;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
 }

#checkmark {
 font-weight: lighter;
 fill: #fff;
 margin: -3.5em auto auto 20px;
  }

 #status {
font-weight: lighter;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-size: 1em;
margin-top: -.2em;
margin-bottom: 0;
 }

#lower-side {
padding: 2em 2em 5em 2em;
background: #F0F0F0;
display: block;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
 }

#message {
font-family: Arial;
margin-top: -.5em;
color: #757575;
letter-spacing: 1px;
 }



.button {

background-color:#333;
font-family: Arial;
color: white;
padding-top: 14px;
padding-right: 32px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
padding-left: 32px;

text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: -5px 0 0 320px;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
align-items:center;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border:1px solid #333;
border-bottom-width: 3px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px #4747471;
}

h1{
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
font-size: 31px;
 }

.text{
padding: 20px 0;
float: left;

 }
.text p{
padding-left: 320px;
width:450px;
}
.text-img{
float: right;
    height: 470px;
width: 353px;
background: url("{% static 'landingpage.jpg'%}");
padding: 0 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: Arial;
}
.text-img h2{
color: white;
margin: 0;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 100px;
  }

.text-img p{
color: white;
margin: 0;
font-size: 14px;
 }

.text-img input{
display: block;
width: 96%;
}

.text-img input[type="email"]{
background: #333;
border: 0;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
color: white;
  }

 .text-img input[type="email"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{
color: #587974;
 }
 .text-img input[type="email"]:-moz-placeholder{
color: #587974;
 }
.text-img input[type="email"]::-moz-placeholder{
color: #587974;
 }
.text-img input[type="email"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #587974;
 }
.text-img input[type="submit"]{
float: right;
margin-top: 30px;
width: 50%;
}
.clearfix{
clear: both;
 }

footer p{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;

    padding: 12px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
   }


 </style>



<body> 
 <div>
  <center><img src="{% static 'Neoticlogo.png'%}" height="130px"  alt="Logo"></center>

 <h1 style="text-align: center;">
 <font face="Arial" color=" #587974">Beat the markets with AI </font>
 </h1>

 </div>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div class='row' style="background: #3CB371" >
  <div class="col-lg-4">

   <div class="text">
    <p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:12; " align="justify"> Neotic is a trading support platform that allows traders to test trading strategies and provides related trading recommendations leveraging artificial intelligence, without writing any single line of code.</p> 

    <p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:12;" align="justify"> The artificial intelligence is based on a machine learning algorithm that incorporates corporate fundamentals, historical prices and financial news.</p> 
    <b> <p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:14; " align="justify"> We are upgrading our services and revamping our brand</p> </b>

   <form>
  <input type='button' class='button' id='run' value= 'Access our old platform' onclick="window.location.href='http://www.dailystockselect.com/'" />
   </form>
  </div>

 <div class="text-img" >
 <h2>Trader or investment fund?</h2>
 <p>Leave your email to be notified when the new service is ready.</p>
  <form action="/subscribe/" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
   <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required/>
   <input type="submit" value="I am interested">
  </form>
  {% if success %}
  <body id="overlay" style="filter: blur(2px);" >

  <div id="messageContainer"  >
   <div id='card' class="animated fadeIn">
    <div id='upper-side'>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M131.583,92.152l-0.026-0.041c-0.713-1.118-2.197-1.447-3.316-0.734l-31.782,20.257l-4.74-12.65
c-0.483-1.29-1.882-1.958-3.124-1.493l-0.045,0.017c-1.242,0.465-1.857,1.888-1.374,3.178l5.763,15.382
c0.131,0.351,0.334,0.65,0.579,0.898c0.028,0.029,0.06,0.052,0.089,0.08c0.08,0.073,0.159,0.147,0.246,0.209
c0.071,0.051,0.147,0.091,0.222,0.133c0.058,0.033,0.115,0.069,0.175,0.097c0.081,0.037,0.165,0.063,0.249,0.091
c0.065,0.022,0.128,0.047,0.195,0.063c0.079,0.019,0.159,0.026,0.239,0.037c0.074,0.01,0.147,0.024,0.221,0.027
c0.097,0.004,0.194-0.006,0.292-0.014c0.055-0.005,0.109-0.003,0.163-0.012c0.323-0.048,0.641-0.16,0.933-0.346l34.305-21.865
C131.967,94.755,132.296,93.271,131.583,92.152z" />
    <circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="109.486" cy="104.353" r="32.53" />
  </svg>
  <h3 id='status'>
  Success
</h3>
</div>
<div id='lower-side'>
<p id='message'>
  Thank you for your interest in Neotic.
</p>
<div>
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" onclick="$('#card').hide(); body.style.filter = 'none' ;">X</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

{% endif %}

 </div>
 </div>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution that I can think of:

```
{% if success %}
<body>

<div id="messageContainer">
<div  id="overlay" style="filter: blur(2px);">
<div id='card' class="animated fadeIn">
<div id='upper-side'>

...

  <h3 id='status'>
  Success
  </h3>
</div>
<div id='lower-side'>
<p id='message'>
  Thank you for your interest in Neotic.
</p>
<div>
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" onclick="$('#card').hide(); body.style.filter = 'none' ;">X</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing: putting up another `div` so adding the `blur` attribute to that, thus protecting the `messagecontainer` from the overlay.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work ! 
I have before if success lots of div .

Comment: there are `div`s before the `body` tag?

Comment: yes when i click on success .. the body becomes blur without the message container

Comment: before the success everything is normal

Comment: are you sure wrapping everything in a `div` doesn't work? It seems to be working perfectly fine for me

Comment: Can i send you my complete html ?

Comment: move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148307/remove-blur-from-message-container)